# TS doesn't see default props in React function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My code

```
interface ButtonProps {
  onClick?: () => void
}

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  const wrapClick = () => {
    onClick() // TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
  }

  return <button onClick={wrapClick}>button</button>
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {},
}
```

In this case, everything works

```
const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  const wrapClick = () => {
    onClick && onClick()
  }

  return <button onClick={wrapClick}>button</button>
}
```

and in this

```
const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick = () => {} }) => {
  const wrapClick = () => {
    onClick()
  }

  return <button onClick={wrapClick}>button</button>
}
```

Is there a way to use default props to solve this problem ? Since I have large components with a lot of properties.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the question mark behind `onClick` ?

Comment: @TobiasS. 
In some cases , you do not need to pass onclick and you want to have a solution that allows you to do this without errors . 
Example :
<Button /> or <Button onClick={onClick}/> 
it is necessary that there are no errors in both cases.

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with the solutions you already have? They seem to be working fine. Since you can not put default values inside an interface, there probably isn't another solution.

Comment: The last solution is recommended usage with typescript.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to solve this problem with default props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onClick property in the props object is marked as optional by using a question mark, so we can't directly invoke the function.

To solve the error, use the optional chaining (?.) operator when calling the function.

```
import { FC } from "react";

interface ButtonProps {
  onClick?: () => void;
}

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  const wrapClick = () => {
    onClick?.();
  };

  return <button onClick={wrapClick}>button</button>;
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {}
};

export default Button;
```

[Code Sandbox : DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-v1mj1j?file=/src/Button.tsx)

Comment: This solution is the most convenient for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Non-`null` assertion operator (postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to let TypeScript know your default `onClick(): void` is not `null`/`undefined` (which it thinks it is because of `IButtonProps.onClick: () => void | undefined`, which is used by `Button` (`FC<IButtonProps>`, `FC<T>.defaultProps` is of type `T & { children?: Node }` if I remember correctly)).

```
interface IButtonProps {
  onClick?: () => void;  // No event args?
}

const Button: FC<IButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    onClick = Button.defaultProps.onClick!,
  } = props;

  const wrapClick = (/* No event args? */) => {
    onClick();
  };

  return <button onClick={wrapClick}>button</button>;
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => {},
};
```